# Not able to mock the django query object that is iterating through for loop

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, mocking

I am trying to mock the django query object while iterating through for loop.

```
  for row in MyModel.objects.filter(ListId=id):
```

I am getting the **'TypeError: 'Mock' object is not iterable'**

Below is my approach

```
    MyModel_mock_data = mock.MagicMock(spec=MyModel)
    MyModel_mock_data.state='x',
    MyModel_mock_data.product='y',
    MyModel_mock_data.type='z',
    MyModel_mock_data.effectiveDate='2019-04-10'

    MyModel_queryset = Mock()
    MyModel_mock.filter.return_value = MyModel_queryset
    MyModel_mock.exists.return_value = True
```

I am trying to test below django query inside my method.

```
if MyModel.objects.filter(
    state=state,
    product=product,
    type=FormType,
    effectiveDate=effectiveDate
).exists():

    print("before for >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", MyModel.objects.filter(
    state=state,
    product=product,
    type=FormType,
    effectiveDate=effectiveDate
).exists())
    for item in MyModel.objects.filter(
        state=state,
        product=product,
        type=FormType,
        effectiveDate=effectiveDate
    ):
        print("inside for >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", item)
        formNameInDb = (item.fileId).formName
        print("formNameInDb>>>>>>>>>>>", formNameInDb)
        # formName already exist in DB
        if formNameInDb == formName:
            return True
```

Can anyone help to solve the chain queries. Any help or lead, I will really appreciate.
Please let me know if any information required.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Instead of assigning `return_value` to a Mock (which is, as the error message states, not iterable), you need wrap your mock in an iterable, e.g. a `list` or `tuple`:

```
 @mock.patch('myapp.models.MyModel.objects')
   def test_myMethod(self, mock_MyModel):
     mock_queryset = Mock()
     mock_MyModel.filter.return_value = [mock_queryset]
```

Comment: I have updated by problem with my new approach but still I have same error . can help me into it.

Comment: The code still repeats the earlier problem; you must specify the return value of filter to be a list (of one mock), not a mock.

Comment: mock , after trying this *MyModel.filter.return_value = [mock_queryset] * . It is throwing now. *AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'exists' * . Do I have to again mock it for 'exists()', i tried many things but didn't get success. :-(